# Json to pd.DataFrame: parsing to datetime with different timestamp formats

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, parsing

I am working with a large JSON file (around 40 million rows) from Google Takeout. An example of the data can be seen in the image below. I load the data into a `pd.DataFrame` and I change the timestamps to `pd.datetime`. The timestamps are almost always in the format `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f`, which I use to parse the timestamps to datetimes. The following code works:

```
self.df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(self.df["timestamp"], 
    format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"
)
```

However, as can be seen in the highlighted timestamp in the image, sometimes the timestamp does not include the nanoseconds (which matches: `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"`). This results in an error when parsing:

`"ValueError: unconverted data remains when parsing with format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f": "Z" at position 0."`

My question: how do I parse the entire JSON with different formats, that support timestamps with and without nanoseconds? I could pre-process the JSON file before parsing by looping over it and removing the nanoseconds from the strings, but that seems very inefficient to me. A small reproducible sample can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/hGj0XM9p).

[image]

Comment: Looks like pretty standard ISO format; just use `pd.to_datetime(self.df["timestamp"])`? Besides, in pandas 2 you could specify `format="ISO8601"` which might help with performance ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)).